# how to get the next random element knowing the previous one

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a a fixed list of objects (almost it is actually coming from a db) and i want to be able to pick one element at a time and never pick one that was seen previously before doing the all set of elements 
Any idea how to do that ?

it is related to getting a randint(0, N) but knowing the last pick . Can i force the seed maybe ?

---

**EDIT**

I should have been more explicit. Sorry for that. 
When I do a request to my view/function , I get only one element every time.

On next request i want to pass only the last one i got as argument and get another randomly from the same list. But as python is using some kind of linear congruential generator (u_1 = f(u_0) ) , i would like to be able to seed it with my old value in order to get the next one. It does not need to be perfect statistaclly but roughly random

```
def f(old = None):
  l = range(100)
  some_number = ??(l, old)
  return some_number
```

Comment: If you want selection without replacement, remove from the set any elements that are selected.

Comment: your edit makes no sense. So basically it could pick 1 then 2, then 1, then 2...  there's only a 1-depth memory of what not to pick.

Comment: I've attempted to take into account the new request in an edit but I'm not sure what exactly you're after now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: if you have an linear random generator it does have a sense. Getting the next random number only required the previous one. And it is that specific property that i would like to use but i don't know if it is exposed

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method would be to simply use `random.shuffle()` on your list of objects and then iterate through that list.

```
import random

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

random.shuffle(lst)
print lst
```

If you didn't want to modify the list itself, create a list of indices.

```
import random

indices = range(len(lst))

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

random.shuffle(indices)

for index in indices:
    print lst[index]
```

EDIT

Now that the question is changed, I think you could take this principle a little further for that purpose. Just rebuild the list of available indices.

```
def return_random(indices, last_chosen):
    remaining_indices = [index for index in indices if index != last_chosen]
    return random.choice(remaining_indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
    import random
    def f(n):
        random.seed(n)
        return random.randint(0, 100)
```

May not be good for modeling or statistical analysis - but it is random, and it is based on previous number.

Comment: Thx Alex, simple and what i need. I do not need any statistical property but being a  pure function

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to work well with small seed numbers. Something based on random.shuffle should work better.